# It is possible to create branching questions with inquirer?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, inquirer

```
const employeeQuestion = [
    {
        type: "list",
        name: "employeeTitle",
        message: "What's the employee's title",
        choices: ["Engineer", "Intern"]

    },

    //when role is engineer is true, ask this question
    {
        when: input => {
            return input.role == "Engineer"
        },
        type: "input",
        name: "github",
        message: "Enter your github username:",
    },

    //when role is intern is true, ask this question
    {
        when: input => {
            return input.role == "Intern"
        },
        type: "input",
        name: "school",
        message: "What's the school you enrolled in ?",
    },

]
```

The idea is I want to utilize inquirer's **when** method so the question whether to ask about the user's github or school is dependent on the answer on the employee's title. But when i run node on the command line, the question asking for github / school never appeared. I wonder if I used the method wrong or if there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inquirer's **when** method is definitely the correct one for this situation!

There are two possible reasons:

1. You are using `input.role` but never defining a `role` value in the answers hash. You need to refer to the **name** value from the earlier question, in this case, `input.employeeTitle`.
2. If reason 1 does not fix it, try expanding your function a bit. **when** needs to take in the answers hash as an input, then apply the conditional to that and explicitly return a Boolean. Ex.

   ```
   {
        type: "input",
        name: "github",
        message: "Enter your github username:",
        when: (answers) => {
            if (answers.employeeTitle === "Engineer") {
                return true;
            }
   }
   ```